# Automated vs Custom Lucene Scoring

Tags: java, search, lucene

I have started working on Lucene (v 4.10.2) Search Based Ranking/Scoring.

**Consider the following Scenario:** I am searching 'Mark' in my search box. Auto-complete result shows Top 5 people named 'Mark' (although there might be hundreds of Mark in the Lucene index files).

I go on Mark Zuckerberg's profile which is placed on 4th place in the beginning of the search. Say I have clicked his profile a lot of times. Now according to me, next time I search 'Mark', 'Mark Zuckerberg' should come at the top of the list.

Several questions coming in my mind (even I don't know that I'm on right track or not):

1) How to achieve this using Lucene library ? (Automated or custom based scoring)

2) Can we change the scoring after any search?

3) Does Lucene library stores the scoring in indexed files?

4) Can we store the scoring in the indexed files?

Please let me know if I'm on the right track or not.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I would try, regardless any performance and index 
maintainability issues for now.

I would add a multivalued string field for users that have at least once hit the
profile document.

Every time a user (say "vipul") hits an auto-completed profile (say 
"Mark Zuckerberg") I would add the username to the special multivalued string 
field in the profile document.

When searching I would add a term in the special field with the current username
as the value, boosting it, so it comes first in the searches.

Now, some performance. Since updating the full document only to update a single
field could be quite expensive, I would try something with the 
[SortedSetDocValuesField](https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_9_0/core/org/apache/lucene/document/SortedSetDocValuesField.html). I honestly haven't tried anything yet with this 
relatively new field. But if I understand well, it was designed for 
situations like this.

Comment: your explanation is good but not completely relevant to my question asked. Do you want to say that I should add a new StringField in the document where I put the usernames who searched 'Mark Zuck..' so that the name gets boost up in the search?

Comment: Yes. A new string field with the usernames that once selected the document ("Mark Zuckerberg", the full name, not partial auto-completed values).